# Get all Integer data type fields using reflection

Tags: java, reflection

I want to find the data type of field using its name.
I get Type from \

```
Class<?> type = f.getType()
```

but can't determine which is Integer or String or other.
How compare type is Integer or String or Other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `<class>.class` structure and compare the type. You can get the type with the `getClass` method.

```
Class<?> type = f.getClass();
if (type == Integer.class) {
    // integer 
} else if (type == String.class) {
    // string
} else {
    // other
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
       if (f.getType().getName().equals(String.class.getName())) {
           System.out.println("String");
       }
       if (f.getType().getName().equals(Integer.class.getName())) {
           System.out.println("Integer");
       }
```

Comment: Why are the `getName()` calls necessary?

Comment: There is no need to use names. `Class` supports `equals` for checking class equality, and also reuses the `Class` objects in a way that you can just use `==`.